# Can an HTML checkbox value hold a boolean instead of a string?

Tags: html, forms

HTML Input values hold strings.

**For example:**  This holds the string "yes".

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkThis" value="yes">
```

However for checkboxes sometimes it would be convenient if the value was the boolean True.  Obviously the value can be transformed into a boolean after the form has been submitted.  However is there a way to store the value as a boolean to begin with?

Comment: On client side you have the checked property. On server side, the value will be submitted if checkbox is checked, so you can transform your checkboxes form result into boolean quite easy.

Comment: @SilviuBerce That's how I'm doing it and it works great.  I just wondered if there was a clever way I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes use booleans by default, like using `document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked` in Javascript will return True or False depending on if it is checked or not.

Of course the code I just provided assumes that your checkbox has an ID of `mycheckbox`.

You are using what appears to be the value when evaluating the state of the checkbox, but you should use the `.checked` method instead since the value will not change based on if it is checked or not.